# Basic pointer issue

Tags: c++, pointers

I've posted a few pointer-related questions recently. I've tried to unite the confusion I'm suffering in this one post, so apologies if it looks familiar. The question is - why does `funky()` output the string whereas `funkier()` outputs the address? My logic tells me that the latter is what I would expect. Or is this just the way `std::cout` deals with things?

I notice that `printf` behaves the same way.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void funky(const char* a);
void funkier(char* a[]);

int main() {
    const char* y = "message";
    funky(y);

    char* z[3];
    z[0] = "one";
    z[1] = "two";
    z[2] = "three";
    funkier(z);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void funky(const char* a) {
    cout << a << endl; // prints the string.
}

void funkier(char* a[]) {
    cout << a << endl; // prints the address.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `operator<<` for `std::ostream` is overloaded for many different types of the right operand.

If the second operand is a `const char*` it is interpreted as a NUL-terminated string and printed.

If the second operand is a `const void*` it is printed as an address.

There are many other overloads, but these are not relevant here.

The `funky()` call uses the first overload.

But the `funkier` argument is actually a `char**`, which is neither of the above. But it is convertible to `const void*`, not to `const char*`, so the second overload is used.

Beware of `printf()`! That is a C function and it does not detect the type of the arguments. It expects you to pass the right `%s` or `%p` or whatever for each of the arguments. If you use the wrong letter, or pass the wrong argument type, you will probably get *Undefined Behaviour*.

```
char *x = "a";
printf("%s", x); //prints x as string
printf("%p", x); //prints x as pointer
printf("%d", x); //Undefined Behaviour!!!
printf("%d", (int)x); //prints the pointer value as an integer, if it fits
```

Comment: `printf("%p", x);` is technically undefined behaviour , `%p` only prints a `void *`.  (However `char *` must have the same size and representation so it will work unless the compiler is pathological)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yeah, probably. But this is a beginner's question, so I didn't think this nitpickness would be needed.